# Many-to-many relationship between objects of the same type

Tags: mysql, database-design

I want to make a many to many relationship between an object "**Human**" and its parents which are of the **same type** and I wanted to know if this kind of relationship exists in real-life projects or how do experienced developers approach a requirement like that?
What will be the best design to accomplish this task?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a relational database, in general a many-to-many relationship needs a second table.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Parentage (
  child_id INT NOT NULL,
  parent_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (child_id, parent_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (child_id) REFERENCES Human (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES Human (id)
);
```

This is the *relational* way of storing the data, which has advantages that it results in the least redundancy of data, and supports a wide variety of queries with reasonable efficiency.

It also supports a true many-to-many relationship, where a child can have many parents (likely only two biological parents, but with step-parents and guardians and fosters and so on, there could be an unlimited number of humans who count as parents), as well as each parent having many children.

If you want to optimize the table design for a *specific* query, that might be possible. The best design depends on that query you need to optimize, but you haven't described any specific query you will need to run.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make my self clear. I know how to create the relation.
The queries that I might do are retrieving all children of a parent and the parents of a children.

I wanted to know if this is a suitable design for accomplishing tasks like that because It's my first time to get exposed to a case like this and I don't want to create stuff that can affect the system in a bad way, so  I wanted some guidance.

Comment: I recommend using the normalized table design, unless you have an actual case that it can't handle. It's likely that it will work fine for your application, and last for several orders of magnitude of growth.